24.04 metallic sound until I restart pipewire
Thinkpad T14s (5th gen Intel). I often get corrupted sound (at least once a day) where everything sounds metallic. I can solve this by restarting pipewire systemctl --user restart pipewire.service, however that's a very annoying fix which also requires me to restart some apps (notably, MS Teams in Chrome).
Where can I start to debug this?
